# LocationSettingRequest fails to change GPS to PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY

Tags: android, permissions, location, android-gps

My app works fine in turning location on and setPriority to HIGH when the Location setting is off, but it crashes when the location is set as GPS `LocationRequest.PRIORITY_LOW_POWER` instead of displaying the dialog to change to `LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY`

Here is the method that access the SettingClient

```
 public void locationSettingRequest() {
        LocationRequest mLocationRequestHighAccuracy = new LocationRequest().setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        LocationRequest mLocationRequestBalancedPowerAccuracy = new LocationRequest().setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequestHighAccuracy)
                .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequestBalancedPowerAccuracy);

        Task<LocationSettingsResponse> result =
                LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this).checkLocationSettings(builder.build());

        result.addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            try {
                LocationSettingsResponse response = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                // requests here.
                getLoc();

            } catch (ApiException exception) {
                switch (exception.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the
                        // user a dialog.
                        try {
                            // Cast to a resolvable exception.
                            ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) exception;
                            // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                            // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                            resolvable.startResolutionForResult(
                                    SignUpActivity.this,
                                    REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            // Ignore the error.
                        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                            // Ignore, should be an impossible error.
                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                        // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

and I received the response in the OnActivityResult

```
   @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

//        final LocationSettingsStates states = LocationSettingsStates.fromIntent(data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS) {
            switch (resultCode) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    // All required changes were successfully made
                    getLoc();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    finish();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

How do I get the location to change from `LocationRequest.PRIORITY_LOW_POWER` to `HIGH_ACCURACY`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it, I checked if the `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER` is enable. If it not, I display a message to prompt user to change location mode to `HIGH_ACCURACY`. I then call `settingRequest` if `NETWORK_PROVIDER` is enable.
Not sure if it's the right way, but it worked.

```
public void checkLocationMode() {
        LocationManager loc = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (!loc.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Turn location mode to High Accuracy.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        } else {
            settingRequest();
        }
    }
```